# Search by Date and show data in BootstrapTable

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-table

What I want to do is to input some date time range and show me the data in a BootstrapTable. I am not able to do it.
I have two php files one is my WebSite and the other is the MySql query.
So this where I load the Input data fields and my BootstrapTabel:

```
<div class='col-md-2 float-left'>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">Datum von:</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="dateVon" name="dateVon" value="2022-01-01" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2022-01-01" aria-describedby="dateVon">
                                </div>
                        
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-md-2 float-left'>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">Datum bis:</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input id="dateBis" name="dateBis" value="2022-01-31" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2022-01-31" aria-describedby="dateBis">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" disabled>
                                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Delete
                            </button>
                            <button id="refresh" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="refreshFunction(dateVon,dateBis);">
                                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Refresh
                            </button>

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">


                        <table id="table" 
                        data-toolbar="#table-responsive" 
                        data-search="true" 
                        data-show-refresh="true" 
                        data-show-toggle="true" 
                        data-show-fullscreen="true" 
                        data-show-columns="true" 
                        data-show-columns-toggle-all="true" 
                        data-detail-view="true" 
                        data-show-export="true" 
                        data-click-to-select="true" 
                        data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter" 
                        data-minimum-count-columns="2" 
                        data-pagination="true" 
                        data-id-field="ID" 
                        data-page-size="50" 
                        data-page-list="[50, 100, all]" 
                        data-show-footer="true" 
                        data-side-pagination="client"
                        data-url="verpAnrufData.php" 
                        data-response-handler="responseHandler" 
                        data-detail-view="true">
                            </table>

<script>
                                var $table = $('#table')
                                var $remove = $('#remove')
                                var selections = []

                                function getIdSelections() {
                                    return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function(row) {
                                        return row.ID
                                    })
                                }

                                function responseHandler(res) {
                                    $.each(res.rows, function(i, row) {
                                        row.state = $.inArray(row.ID, selections) !== -1
                                    })
                                    return res
                                }

                                function totalTextFormatter(data) {
                                    return 'Total'
                                }

                                function totalNameFormatter(data) {
                                    return data.length
                                }

                                function totalPriceFormatter(data) {
                                    var field = this.field
                                    return '$' + data.map(function(row) {
                                        return +row[field].substring(1)
                                    }).reduce(function(sum, i) {
                                        return sum + i
                                    }, 0)
                                }

                                function initTable() {
                                    $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
                                        locale: 'de-DE',
                                        columns: [{
                                            field: 'state',
                                            checkbox: true,
                                            rowspan: 1,
                                            align: 'center',
                                            valign: 'middle'
                                        }, {
                                            field: 'id',
                                            title: 'ID',
                                            rowspan: 1,
                                            align: 'center',
                                            valign: 'middle',
                                            sortable: true,
                                            footerFormatter: totalTextFormatter
                                        }, {
                                            field: 'name',
                                            title: 'Kunde',
                                            sortable: true,
                                            align: 'left',
                                            footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter
                                        }, {
                                            field: 'callerid',
                                            title: 'Anrufer',
                                            sortable: true,
                                            align: 'left'
                                        }, {
                                            field: 'datetime_entry_queue',
                                            title: 'DatumZeit',
                                            sortable: true,
                                            align: 'left'
                                        }, {
                                            field: 'duration_wait',
                                            title: 'Warteschleife (sec)',
                                            sortable: true,
                                            align: 'left'
                                        }]
                                    })

                                    $table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' +
                                        'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table',
                                        function() {
                                            $remove.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length)
                                            //$btnEdit.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length)
                                            // save your data, here just save the current page
                                            selections = getIdSelections()
                                            // push or splice the selections if you want to save all data selections
                                        })
                                    $table.on('all.bs.table', function(e, name, args) {
                                        console.log(name, args)
                                    })
                                }

                               

                                $(function() {
                                    initTable()
                                    $('#locale').change(initTable)
                                })


                                function refreshFunction() {
                                    var data = {
                                        dateVon: $("input[id='dateVon']").val(),
                                        dateBis: $("input[id='dateBis']").val()
                                    };
                                    $.ajax({
                                        method: "post",
                                        url: "verpAnrufData.php",
                                        data: data,
                                        success: function(response) {
                                            /* console.log(data); */
                                           /*  params.success({
                                                "rows": data,
                                                "total": data.length
                                            }, null, {}); */
                                            //initTable();
                                            $table.bootstrapTable('refresh')
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
```

and this is my MySql php file:

```
<?php

include "dbConn.php";
$dateVon = $_POST["dateVon"];
$dateBis = $_POST["dateBis"]; 

$sqltran = mysqli_query($db,    "SELECT     ce.id,
                                    ce.callerid,
                                    ce.datetime_entry_queue,
                                    ce.duration_wait,
                                    convert(cast(convert(cae.name using  latin1) as binary) using utf8) name   
                                    FROM call_center.call_entry ce, call_center.campaign_entry cae
                                    WHERE  ce.id_campaign = cae.id
                                    AND datetime_entry_queue BETWEEN '$dateVon 00:00:00' AND '$dateBis 23:59:59'
                                    AND status = 'abandonada'
                                    ORDER BY name, datetime_entry_queue ASC;");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sqltran) ;
$arrVal = array();
 
 $i=1;
 while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
 

 $name = array(
 'id' => $rowList['id'],
 'name'=> $rowList['name'],
 'callerid'=> $rowList['callerid'],
 'datetime_entry_queue'=> $rowList['datetime_entry_queue'],
 'duration_wait'=> $rowList['duration_wait'],
 ); 

 array_push($arrVal, $name); 
 $i++; 
 }
 $allData = array(
    'total' => $count, 
    'rows' => $arrVal,
    );
echo json_encode($allData); 
mysqli_close($db);  // close connection
```

If i harde code the Dates in this file like this:

```
$dateVon = "2022-01-01";
$dateBis = "2022-12-31";
```

Then I can see the data, but then I am not able to input another dates and refresh it.
I am desperate I can not make it work, pls help. :)

Comment: The response of your AJAX call is JSON, but you're not doing anything with it. Perhaps start with `let data = JSON.parse(response);` to get at the data? See: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: But there are simply to many potential problems with this code to really help you. You need to concentrate on one problem at the time in a question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer of my problem, it was in the ajax function and the way I was responding the cell. Thx KIKO Software for the sugesstion.

```
function refreshFunction() {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        method: "POST",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        url: "verpAnrufData.php",
                                        data: { 
                                            dateVon: $("input[id='dateVon']").val(),
                                            dateBis: $("input[id='dateBis']").val()
                                        },
                                        success: function(response) {
                                            console.log(response);
                                            $table.bootstrapTable('load',{
                                                "rows": response,
                                                "total": response.length
                                            }, null, {});
                                        }
                                    })
                                };
```